# Why is HTTP not a messaging protocol? (according to RabbitMQ)

Tags: http, rabbitmq, amqp, stomp

In this [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html), MQTT, AMQP and STOMP are referred to as supported message protocols. If you consider [the differences between MQTT, AMQP and STOMP](https://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html), this is completely understandable to me. 
However, at the end of this article it becomes confusing. That's about HTTP. This paragraph states that "HTTP is not a course not a messaging protocol". I had thought that HTTP would also be directly supported by RabbitMQ in one way or another, but is only supported for 'low volume messaging purposes' ( diagnostics for example) and for direct use in HTML. 
If half the world uses HTTP web api services, why HTTP could not be shared among the messaging protocols. Why is HTTP not a messaging protocol and what is the definition RabbitMQ uses of a messaging protocol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP falls squarely into the synchronous [request-response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request%E2%80%93response) protocols category. This is the very opposite of asynchronous [message passing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing) protocols typical of [Message-Oriented Middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware).

The 'half of the world' that uses HTTP for web api services does not use it as a [loose coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) *messaging* based web API service, but as a tightly coupled request-response based API.

Messaging protocols come with certain characteristics (at-least-once, exactly-once, at-most-once, exactly-once-in-order etc) which are provided by the protocol definition and implementation. Attempting to do *messaging* over HTTP quickly devolves into replicating these requirements (retries, sequence numbers, duplicate handling etc) at a layer *above* HTTP and deprecating HTTP to a transport layer which offers little value from a *messaging* point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The categorization synchronous request-response versus asynchronous message passing protocols I was looking for. 

Can I simply state that HTTP is synchronous communication between one sender and one receiver and that _messaging_ is asynchronous communication between one sender and one or multiple recipients, where a broker or a stack on both sides provides mechanisms like queuing, acknowledgements, time outs  ... on top of the protocol ?

Comment: From the standpoint of the protocol, they are different. HTTP often (though not always) creates a new TCP connection with each successive request to the server, and it has its own handshake, etc. AMQP, for example, is much different down at the actual protocol (bits/bytes) level and how it manages the socket. Which is one reason why you're gonna have a tough time with firewalls.

Comment: @CoffeCold right, a messaging product will handle the local storage (queuing) and retry/reliability out-of-the-box. And speaking of firewalls, they are *the* reason why sometimes one uses HTTP/S as the transport protocol for higher layer messaging protocols. Outbound HTTP/S connectivity is ubiquitous.